# Sanctum creates extra sessions, but why?

Tags: php, laravel, session, session-cookies, laravel-sanctum

Super strange issue.

I have SPA Nuxt JS app and Laravel 8 API to power it.

I got the Sanctum to authenticate my SPA but here is the deal - on page load before you log in I am making 3 API calls to get some data to display. Now these three calls they all set XSRF cookies and they all create sessions in Laravel session directory.

After that it uses one of these sessions but I do not understand why the call to data endpoint would create extra session?

These are API endpoints in the API routing file, and do not have any unusual stuff there. Any ideas what could it be?

To my understanding I should not get any session for that!

I've dropped exact config I am using in description of related problem right here: [Laravel API (Sanctum) + nuxt auth - weird cookies behaviour, I don't get it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954961/laravel-api-sanctum-nuxt-auth-weird-cookies-behaviour-i-dont-get-it)

Comment: I would focus less on the XSRF cookie and more on the laravel session cookie. If all 3 requests send one and it's the same one, then no new sessions should be created. If they don't send one then because of the sanctum middleware there will be a new session created for each request which doesn't already include the session cookie

Comment: hey  @apokryfos nice to hear from you again, gotcha so this is some funky timing issue, right? Am I right in saying that I should first check for the cookie in the interceptor perhaps and then get the cookie if it is missing and only then continue any other request?

Comment: They have to be 3 different ones because laravel spawns 3 different session files.

Comment: I'm not sure of your setup here. You mention the issue is in your login page. Is the login page on a separate app (i.e. not on the Laravel app)? If that's the case then I think you should send one of the requests first to initialise the session (e.g. maybe the one [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection)) and then send the other two once the first one has finished so you're sure you've got a session and token?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes so long story short: separate SPA(NuxtJS) powered by laravel 8 API, on a landing page I display some content for guests just some text from API endpoint. 3 API calls 3 endpoints. These API calls do not require to be logged in. They all set cookies, session ones and the xsrf for some reason. These are in api.php and use API middleware. I have no clue how in the world they would start a session, they are not behind sanctum middleware. I assume sanctum just globally starts the session for any request due to its extra middleware in API group in Kernel.php

Comment: These endpoints do not use web middleware either so it is gotta be sanctum doing that. But like you suggested I will first check out the cookie situation in Nuxt app and then get the cookie if needed first. I think Nuxt might have option just for doing that so it might be easier.

Comment: Just to add @apokryfos, I just wansn't sure if this was the right approach as Sanctum docs says to call the cookie endpoint before logging in and doesn't mention that I will have to do that before I start calling my API. So it just felt weird. So thanks for confirming.

Comment: The API middleware that sanctum adds does start the session as it turns out, making API routes also create sessions, so if you want truly stateless requests you could make a 3rd route group that does not use that middleware

Comment: I might go that way later on. Rn I am just implementing cookie check in Axios so I will always have the cookie first. Thanks again for the good advice.